# Form.is_valid() returns False?

Tags: django

**Why am I asking question despite already been asked?** I read many question posted on Stack Overflow but I am not able to fix the code as I am new to Python Language.

**What am I trying to do**: Simply trying to take the input from user and return an `HttpResponse` (if successfully). Otherwise, an error `HttpResponse` message to return.

**Problem** : The `MyForm.is_valid()` in *Forms.py* is always returning `False`! I tried many solutions posted on previous questions and also read the documentary thrice but not able to understand, what am I doing wrong?

### Views.Py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import PostForm
.
.
. <<code here>>

def register(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                Myform =  PostForm(request.POST)
                if Myform.is_valid():                                
                            return HttpResponse("<h1>Is_Valid is TRUE.</h1>")
                else:
                   return HttpResponse("<h1>Is_Valid is False.</h1>")               
            else:
                    return HttpResponse("<h1> GET REQUEST>>>> </h1>")
```

### Forms.Py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
                 model= Post
                 fields = ['Username']
```

### Models.Py

```
from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
                    Username = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

                    def __str__(self):
                                return self.name
```

### HTML CODE

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form method="POST" class="post-form" action="{% url 'submit' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group"> <!-- Full Name -->
      <label for="Username" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" name="full_name" placeholder="Enter the name of Patient here.">
      </div>      

     <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit Button -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit!</button>
      </div>                 
   </form>  
  </div>    
       <hr/>
{% endblock %}
```

### Urls.Py

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from .  import views
urlpatterns = [      

url(r'^/submit$', views.register , name = 'submit'),                                                      

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your input should be `username`:
This is how you send this value to the form.

> NOTE: It's better to use the django form, that you've already done with ModelForm

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter the name of Patient here.">
```

Comment: Do Django retreive values of form from name or id??

Comment: when you submit, you actually send the value inside a dict where the `input name` is the key, and `value` the value. so when you do YourForm(request.POST), you send all the values to the form, then the latter will retrieve the value with the name as the key in the dict

Comment: Great! Got some idea, how the rendering happens in Django!! Is it necessary that the name in the HTML input field should match `ModelForms` >>`MetaClass` Fields and the ModelsClass field?

Comment: Of course, It's suggested that you use the Django form in your template instead of doing it yourself since you already have a `ModelForm`

Comment: I tried including the Django Forms in my template last whole night but that made me awake whole night slapped me with some error somewhat ` {{ form.p }} not defined``. You have said in answer "Forms are better than ModelForms??" I read from documentation ModelForms are better than simple forms??

Comment: I said:  **it's better to use the django forms** `forms.ModelForm` `forms.Form`